# Using JpaRepository instead of CrudRepository

Tags: spring, jpa

I've read that if possible you should use `CrudRepository` or `PagingAndSortingRepository` over `JpaRepository` so that you don't couple your code to a store-specific implementation, but is there any instance where `JpaRepository` would be the better choice?

For my application, we need to use the `saveAndFlush()` method and `flush()` method to flush the database changes right away because we are trying to merge two entities together and don't want to run into errors with unique key conditions.

For example:

```
public class User {
    @Id
    String userId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private Collection<Address> addresses;

    // getter and setter methods
}

public class Address {

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private  User user;

    // Other fields
    // getter and setter methods
}

public void mergeDuplicateUserAddresses(User user, User duplicateUser) {
    String userId = user.getUserId();
    List<Address> addresses = duplicateUser.getAddresses()

    for (Address address : addresses) {
        address.setUser(userId);
        addressesRepository.saveAndFlush(address);
    }
}
```

For this instance, I see using `JpaRepository` over `CrudRepository`, but would there be an alternative to make it less store-specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a JpaRepository and be happy with it.
A change of the underlying data source type is in realtiy a rare case and when it happens there are larger changes necessary anyways. Different data source types need in reality different handling. 
I know that it often happens that some guys says you should abstract from the type of data source so that you can change it easily. But not sure if they ever tried it.

Some arguments why it would not work (in case you need to argue with someone)

- Change of the underlying relational database does often not work. Yes JPA should be an abstraction layer for it, but it does not work in every case. You also will run into troubles when you change your jpa provider. They all have their characteristics.
- When you swap your date source f.e. from relational to noe4j. What do you do with your @Query stuff. I am sorry that I have to say that but neo4j does not understand sql.
- Transaction handling is something you always have to keep in mind. Does your data source supports transactions at all and how do they behave. For example relation and neo4j. Both have a transaction system, but they work complelty different and you can run  into troubles when migrate your code directly to neo4j. The reason for that is that neo4j has a more strict locking behaviour.
- Your business layer may depend for performance reason on a specific fetching behaviour, but what happens if you swap your data source type. Do these different data source types support alternative fetching behaviours. Or is it necessary to modify how the business layer works at all because of that?

And of the story. Change of the data source type means usually more troubles than implementing a different interface.